# $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$. Show that $f$ is continuous.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $ f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$.

How can I show that $f$ is continuous, when $f$ is continuous at $f(0)$?